# No connection to WoframAlpha with v10.1

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, internet

I have a problem with my connection to WolframAlpha with the new version 10.1.
And I can't figure out what causes it, because it works with version 10.0.

[image]

Also, I have a connection to the data server (got the population of France).

Testing the Internet Connectivity in preferences is also no problem:
[image]
Seems I just didn't get a connection to Wolfram Alpha.

Is there someone with the same or a similar problem ... or even better, someone with a solution?

EDIT:
OS is Windows 7 (64-bit) with a proxy server.

Comment: Works for me on 10.1 on OSX Mavericks.  What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Win7 64bit

Comment: It works for me with 10.1.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I forgot to say I'm behind a proxy. But as said: with the same settings, it works ob previous versions.

Comment: Try playing with the settings in Help->Internet Connectivity

Comment: @GordonCoale I played a lot with these settings: Only with 'use proxy settings from my system' I'll get a connection to pacletserver. Wolfram|Alpha is the only thing I can't access with 10.1 (10.0 and 9 working)

Comment: Have you tried [Wolfram System Internet Connectivity](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InternetConnectivity.html) and [Troubleshooting Internet Connectivity Problems](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TroubleshootingInternetConnectivity.html)

Comment: @Louis of course I have. Meanwhile it worked with v10.3 (with a workaround) but doesn't work with 10.4 again.